# Redux reducers unit testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux

I have a problem while doing the unit testing for reducers.

The problem is something like this:

I am trying the expected and result value should be equal and while creating the new state I was passing a action to create the new state 
The error is something like ...action type is not matching with the result .

Code sample:

```
it('should transform in to new state',()=> {
  const state={} 
  const action={ type: actionTypes.customerLookup, value :1 , customerRecords:{ reqStatus: false, message: 'No records found', searchResult:[{"records":1}] } };
  const expected={ customerRecords:{ reqStatus: false, message: 'No records found', searchResult:[{"records":2}] }};
  assert.deepEqual(createCusRecState(state,action),expected);
```

Comment: Code sample? Error message? Censor/Sanitize then post them.

Comment: Will attach soon ...thanks for the quicker response

Comment: it('should transform in to new state',()=>
  {

    const state={}

    
const action={

  type: actionTypes.customerLookup,
   
   value :1 ,
  customerRecords:{
    reqStatus: false, message: 'No records found', searchResult:[{"records":1}]
  }
};
const expected={

  customerRecords:{
    reqStatus: false, message: 'No records found', searchResult:[{"records":2}]
  }};
  assert.deepEqual(createCusRecState(state,action),expected);